# Query regarding surprising spike in accuracy of ML model

Tags: cross-validation, accuracy, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I implemented all the major ML models (Logistic Regression, Naive Bayes, SVM, KNN, Decision Tree, Random Forest, Ada Boost & XGBoost) on my dataset. My stratified cross-validation scores are between 70% & 80%. When I implemented my models using grid search, my accuracies shot up & they lie between 90% & 95%. Is this drastic increase in accuracy abnormal & fishy?

**My GridSearch CV code for Logistic Regression-->**

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs, make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
scaled_inputs, targets = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_classes=2, random_state=43)  
#n_samples=no.of test records considered in each fold 
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(scaled_inputs, targets, test_size=0.25, random_state=43)

parameter_grid = {'C':[0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10],   
                  'penalty':['l1', 'l2']  
                  }

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=43)
estimator = GridSearchCV(estimator=lr, param_grid=parameter_grid, \
scoring='accuracy', cv=10, n_jobs=-1)


estimator.fit(x_train, y_train)

print(estimator.best_params_)
print(estimator.best_estimator_)
print(estimator.best_score_)

**Output - {'C': 0.1, 'penalty': 'l2'}
LogisticRegression(C=0.1, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
                   intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None, max_iter=100,
                   multi_class='auto', n_jobs=None, penalty='l2',
                   random_state=43, solver='lbfgs', tol=0.0001, verbose=0,
                   warm_start=False)
0.9279999999999999**

best_penalty = estimator.best_params_['penalty']
best_C = estimator.best_params_['C']

clf_lr = LogisticRegression(penalty=best_penalty, C=best_C)
clf_lr.fit(x_train, y_train)

predictions = clf_lr.predict(x_test)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(f'Accuracy',accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))

**Output -->Accuracy 0.932**
```

Comment: Did you use CV in your GridSearch?

Comment: Yes, I used GridSearchCV.

Comment: @Apoorva is the performance you mention obtained directly from GridSearchCV or obtained from predicting on an unseen test set? When optimizing parameters one should always re-evaluate the best parameters found on an unseen test set, because there is a risk of overfitting.

Comment: I did not understand your question. I edited my question to include the code. Can you please go through it?

Comment: @Apoorva  My question was to make sure that you correctly obtain the performance on the test set, not directly from the best parameters on the training set. But your code looks good to me, I don't see any problem.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This lies in the definition of Grid Search.Grid-search is used to **find the optimal hyperparameters** of a model which results in the most ‘accurate’ predictions.I dont think there ia any kind of abnormality associated with the final prediction .

However **Accuracy is not the only metrics** to evaluate our Classification models. Use **Confusion Matrix** to evaluate your model.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print('Confusion Matrix : \n' + str(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)))
```

After running the above code import classification report It will give you detailed report and you can verfify if there is actually something fishy or not .